# Cite same author and no date multiple times - how to remove brackets around the "a" from for example (Johansson n.d [a])?

Tags: biblatex, brackets, harvard-style, multiple-citations

Im trying to manage references with **biblatex** and the **authoryear-icomp-style** and have a hard time to get the citations and bibliography to look exactly like my university wants them to. Most things I have manage to get correct by reading other peoples questions and answers on this website, but one problem remain. **When I have two different references written by the same author and both references have no date, i would like them to look like as follows below.**

**In the text:**

Word word word word (Johansson u.å. a).

Word word word word (Johansson u.å. b).

**In the bibliography:**

Johansson, S. (u.å. a). Sun. [2018-04-12].

Johansson, S. (u.å. b). Earth. [2018-04-12].

**Instead I get - In the text:**

Word word word word (Johansson u.å.[a]).

Word word word word (Johansson u.å.[b]).

**In the bibliography:**

Johansson, S. (u.å.[a]). Sun. [2018-04-12].

Johansson, S. (u.å.[b]). Earth. [2018-04-12].

**Is there a way to remove the brackets?** I also would like this to work for all types of references.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Biblatex
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sorting=nyc,
    isbn=false, 
    doi=true, 
    dashed=false, 
    maxbibnames=99,
   uniquename=init,
    giveninits 
  ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

%--changes to get citations and bibliography the way my university wants---- 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{swedish}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}

%u.å is swedish for n.d. (no date)
\newcommand{\mkbibnodate}{u\adddot å\adddot}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{year}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{year}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\NewBibliographyString{available}

%tillgänglig is swedish for available
\DefineBibliographyStrings{swedish}{%
  available = {Tillgänglig},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{available}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}

%", Vol. x (x),"
 \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{vol. #1}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
 \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}% 
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

%"ss. XX-XX."
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{ss. #1 \adddot}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\DeclareSortingScheme{nyc}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{\citeorder}
}
%----------------end of changes------------------
\begin{document}
Word word word word \parencite{johansson_sun_????}. \\
Word word word word \parencite{johansson_earth_????}.\\

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(u.å is swedish för n.d (no date)).

My .bib-file:

```
@online{johansson_sun_????,
    title = {Sun},
    author = {Johansson, Sven},
    urldate = {2018-04-12},
}

@online{johansson_earth_????,
    title = {Earth},
    author = {Johansson, Sven},
    urldate = {2018-04-12},
}
```

Comment: The problem is caused by `%\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{year}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}
%\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{year}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}`. Can you show an example what these lines should do? maybe there is another way

Comment: @samcarter, true, but if the default `nodate` string is used there (as opposed to the year number), the brackets will also show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there were some things to be done to achieve what you want. The lines of code that @samcarter mentioned seemed to try to override the underlying mechanism for `labeldate`. I assumed here you wanted to do so only for `online` entries, not letting `urldate` take the place of `labeldate`. That was done by commenting the mentioned lines of code, and redefining the fields `labeldate` takes into account:

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  % \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

You also wanted to have a localized string for "n.d.". That usually should work out of the box. But `swedish.lbx` has a `%FIXME` on that particular string. (You may want to report this at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues. The maintenance of biblatex's localization strings relies on native speakers to supply them). Anyway, for the time being, you have to add the string to your `\DefineBibliographyString`:

```
nodate = {u\adddot å\adddot},
```

Finally, to remove the brackets of extradate, you can use:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{%
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
    {\mknumalph{#1}}
    {\addnbthinspace\mknumalph{#1}}}
```

I also changed your deprecated `\DeclareSortingScheme` for the current `\DeclareSortingTemplate`.

Putting it all together (with a thorough update of your biblatex customizations, by courtesy of @moewe):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Biblatex
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sorting=nyc,
    isbn=false, 
    doi=true, 
    dashed=false, 
    maxbibnames=99,
    uniquename=init,
    giveninits 
  ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

%--changes to get citations and bibliography the way my university wants---- 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

% \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
%   \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
%   \addspace\&\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}


%u.å is swedish for n.d. (no date) % better to do this with the
%localized "nodate" string
% \newcommand{\mkbibnodate}{u\adddot å\adddot}
% \AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{year}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}
% \AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{year}{\restorefield{labelyear}{\mkbibnodate}}{}}

% do not consider "urldate" as a candidate for labeldate
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  % \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

% This is the original definition
% \DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{%
%   \iffieldnums{labelyear}
%     {\mknumalph{#1}}
%     {\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}}
% If you don't want brackets in any case:
\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{%
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
    {\mknumalph{#1}}
    {\addnbthinspace\mknumalph{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
% \NewBibliographyString{available}

%tillgänglig is swedish for available
\DefineBibliographyStrings{swedish}{%
  % available = {Tillgänglig},
  urlfrom     = {Tillgänglig},
  andothers   = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  nodate      = {u\adddot å\adddot}, % added: that currently stands with a % FIXME in swedish.lbx
  pages       = {ss\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}

%", Vol. x (x),"
% \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{vol. #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}% 
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

%"ss. XX-XX."
% \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{ss. #1 \adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}

% \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nyc}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{\citeorder}
}
%----------------end of changes------------------
\begin{document}
Word word word word \parencite{johansson_sun_????}.

Word word word word \parencite{johansson_earth_????}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: A working setup with Overleaf's current biblatex version (3.4) was provided by moewe at https://www.overleaf.com/read/ydgxhpnsfyxs

I leave the code here too:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Biblatex
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sorting=nyc,
    isbn=false, 
    doi=true, 
    dashed=false, 
    maxbibnames=99,
    uniquename=init,
    giveninits 
  ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{johansson_sun_????,
    title = {Sun},
    author = {Johansson, Sven},
    urldate = {2018-04-12},
}

@online{johansson_earth_????,
    title = {Earth},
    author = {Johansson, Sven},
    urldate = {2018-04-12},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%--changes to get citations and bibliography the way my university wants---- 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  % \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

%u.å is swedish for n.d. (no date)
\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{%
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
    {\mknumalph{#1}}
    {\addnbthinspace\mknumalph{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
% \NewBibliographyString{available}

%tillgänglig is swedish for available
\DefineBibliographyStrings{swedish}{%
  urlfrom   = {Tillgänglig},
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  nodate    = {u\adddot å\adddot}, % added: that currently stands with a % FIXME in swedish.lbx
  pages     = {ss\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}

%", Vol. x (x),"
% \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{vol. #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}% 
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

%"ss. XX-XX."
% \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{ss. #1 \adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}

% \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareSortingScheme{nyc}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{\citeorder}
}
%----------------end of changes------------------
\begin{document}
Word word word word \parencite{johansson_sun_????}. \\
Word word word word \parencite{johansson_earth_????}.\\

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Let me just add that instead of `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{vol. #1}` `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}` (or `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}`) would be preferable. Instead of `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{ss. #1 \adddot}` one might want to use `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}`, but that will give 's.' and not 'ss.', so the `pages` bibstring would have to be changed to `ss\adddot`. `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` is `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` now. ...

Comment: ... For `\finalnamedelim` I'd use `\DeclareDelimFormat` now. Finally one need not define the new string `available`, `urlfrom` is already available for that purpose (it needs to be redefined, though because it is `tillg\"anglig fr\aa n`: close, but no cigar)

Comment: @moewe, Thanks! I believe I managed to incorporate everything.

Comment: Huge thanks for all the help @gusbrs and @moewe! I still don't quite get it to work though. I copy-pasted the new code, got error on `\DeclareSortingTemplate`. Changed it back to `\DeclareSortingScheme` so that the preview would update. I added a comma after `andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}` (on line 68). It now looks like this:


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHBQM.png

**The brackets are still there and in the bibliography the parenthesis (u.å. a) and (u.å. b) disappeared somehow. Can anyone of you see why this happens?**

Comment: @MariaHelin If `\DeclareSortingTemplate` throws an error, then that is because your `biblatex` version is outdated. A while ago there was a bug that could affect `nodate`, maybe your version is affected (I don't remember the details, sorry). If you are using a really ancient version, chances are the whole `nodate` business is still working differently. Can you find out the version of `biblatex` you are using? The easiest way is to add `\listfiles` to the beginning of your `.tex` file and then read the version numbers off in the `.log` file.

Comment: @moewe Ok, the .log file says `Package: biblatex 2016/05/14 v3.4 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)`. In a search on google i found v3.11 so I guess my biblatex version is old. Im using Overleaf, so I haven't chosen the biblatex version myself. Do you know if it is possible for me to change to a newer biblatex version in Overleaf?

Comment: No, unfortunately you wouldn't have that option in Overleaf.

Comment: And, indeed, I can reproduce the issues in Overleaf... @moewe, you have a much better knowledge of how older versions were set up. Any ideas? (I had to revert the `finalnamedelim` and the `SortingScheme` to compile. But the issue to be resolved remained unsolved).

Comment: Thanks for all the help gusbrs and @moewe, I accept that I cant solve this in Overleaf. Instead I will try to compile on my own computer, with the latest version of biblatex, in the way you first proposed.

Comment: Oh, if you do have the opportunity to work on an up to date version, that would be indeed ideal.

Comment: @MariaHelin On Overleaf a few of the modernisations shown in this answer need to be rolled back. Most of them you have identified already, but the one central to your question is that you need `\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}` instead of `\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}`: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ydgxhpnsfyxs. But if you have a modern TeX distribution with `biblatex` 3.11 available using that is preferable, I think.

Comment: +1 for all the mind reading!

Comment: @moewe, thanks for the edit. I did let that comma slip...

Comment: @samcarter, what about all the hard work?!  :)

Comment: @gusbrs unfortunately only one vote is possible - all the hard work would only be the second best reason :)

Comment: Ah, @moewe, I shouldn't need to say it, but please do feel free to add an answer with the working set up for the older version, if you think it is worth it. In my view it is, in the end there is plenty of people stuck with older versions (from overleaf to OS repositories installations). There is no need to leave this relegated to an overleaf link in a comment here, I believe.

Comment: Nah, but if you want you can include the link at the end of your answer.